# Как составить SQL запрос если есть поле type JSON

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица `telegrams`
с полями **source, source_type и info**
поле **info** имеет тип **json**

```
{CarriareCode: 'foo', FlightNumber: 'bar'}
```

Как сделать выборку с учетом `info['CarriareCode']` и `info['FlightNumber']`??

```
SELECT
 telegrams.source,
 telegrams.source_type,
 telegrams.info
FROM
 telegrams
WHERE
 telegrams.source = 'web'
AND
 telegrams.source_type = 'SVX'
AND
 --CarriareCode IS NULL
AND
 --FlightNumber IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот пример использования JSON в условиях WHERE:

```
select users.json->'user' as user_name 
from (select '{"user": "Adam"}'::json) users 
where cast(users.json->'user' as text) = '"Adam"'; 

user_name 
-----------
 "Adam"
(1 row)
```

Соответственно для Вашего запроса можно попробовать так:

```
AND
  cast(info->'CarriareCode' as integer) IS NULL
AND
  cast(info->'FlightNumber' as integer) IS NOT NULL
```

Так как система не знает о типе используемых полей в JSON, то необходимо явное преобразование JSON значений, а иначе система выдаст:

> HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You
>   might need to add explicit type casts.